# Decomposition of Multivariate Normal distribution with zero covariance

Tags: multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution, covariance

Is the following true?

N([$s_1, s_2$] | [0,0], [[$\sigma$, 0],[0, $\sigma$]]]) = N($s_1$ | 0, $\sigma$) * N($s_2$ | 0, $\sigma$)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true in the general case. Using the definition of the MVN distribution you can prove that,

N([s1,s2] | [0,0], [[σ, 0],[0, σ]]]) =  σ N(s1$\sqrt(σ)$ | 0, σ) N(s2$\sqrt(σ)$ | 0, σ).